# Unable to retrieve drive id for file uploaded to google drive app folder

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to download a file from google drive app folder and for that I need the drive id (I think so) but with the drive id I get using the code below, I keep getting the file/folder not found error.

```
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClientDrive)
            .listChildren(mGoogleApiClientDrive)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(GoogleSignIn.this, "Unable to get any result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    MetadataBuffer mdb = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                    String ID = mdb.get(0).getDriveId().encodeToString();

                    // Method for downloading data from google drive
                    downloadContent(ID);
                }
            });
```

Certainly I am doing something wrong when trying to fetch the drive id. Tried my luck with getResourceID() too but again with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you double-check your SCOPE? The code should look like this:

```
GoogleApiClient mGAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(act)
  .addApi(Drive.API)
  .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
  .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
  .addConnectionCallbacks( ...  )
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener( ...)
  .setAccountName(email)
  .build();
```

Good Luck